# How to upload an image inside iframe using playwright with JS?

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

[I have the Attached DOM structure as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIr3t.jpg) [Flow is Click select banner button->(inside frame click upload button)-->upon clicking upload button -->Select files button has to be used for upload]
I have used below steps and methods
upload function is happening inside the iframe
Looking forward to your suggestions

```
const mFrame=page.frameLocator('iframe[name="entity_browser_iframe_eb_banner_slides"]').locator('html');

await mFrame.locator("//a[contains(text(),'Upload')]").click(); //clicking upload button

await mFrame.setInputFiles('//*[@id="edit-upload"]/div',filepath); //uploading image
```

upon running above code I am getting below error

```
frame.setInputFiles: Error: Node is not an HTMLInputElement
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually have to click anything for this to work.

Assume I have HTML like this:

```
<div>
    <input name="files" id="files" type="file" size="80" />
    <input id="submit" value="Upload Document" />
</div>
```

I can simply perform the following to set the file for upload upon form submission:

```
const btnUpload = page.locator('#files');
const btnSubmit = page.locator('#submit');

await btnUpload.setInputFiles(fileName);
await btnSubmit.click();
```

That should help you but if it does not work when tweaked to be used in your iframe, please post your html.

EDIT: Without seeing your html, you can probably get away with just this:

```
const frame = page.frameLocator('iframe[name="entity_browser_iframe_eb_banner_slides"]');
await frame.setInputFiles('#edit-upload', filepath);
```

Comment: The flow is click on button-->getting inside a frame ''iframe[name="entity_browser_iframe_eb_banner_slides"]"-->Inside the frame i have upload button-->after clicking the upload button i have one more button name 'select files' to upload the image